# Code Coverage with MSpec

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, code-coverage, mspec

Can anyone recommend a free code coverage tool for use with MSpec on VS2010/.NET4? Can TD.NET do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TD.Net supports code coverage with MSpec (Test with -> Coverage or NCover). You can also use [JetBrains dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/), which also supports MSpec.

Comment: But TeamCity is free, and there's a bundled version of dotCover within TeamCity.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains TeamCity has a free version that includes their dotCover technology as well as an MSpec runner.